# Complete columns

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I explain my problem using a fictitious dataframe. My real dataframe contains more than 200 columns and hundreds of rows.

I have a dataframe (df_tocomplate):

```
df_tocomplate <- data.frame(
  id = c("id1", "id2", "id3"),
  vara.test = c("", "yes", ""), 
  vara.bb = c("yes", "", ""), 
  vara.some = c("", "yes", ""),
  vara = c("bb", "test | some", ""),
  varb.other = c("yes", "", "yes"),
  varb.blop = c("", "yes", "yes"), 
  varb.some = c("yes", "", ""), 
  varb.test = c("", "", "yes"),
  varb = c("other | some", "blop", "other | blop | test"),
  varc.num1 = c(100, 25, 50),
  varc.num2 = c(NA, 75, 25),
  varc.num3 = c(NA, NA, 25),
  varc = c("num1: 100", "num1: 25 | num2: 75", "num1: 50 | num2: 25 | num3: 25"),
  vard.glo1 = c(NA, 15, NA),
  vard.glo2 = c(NA, 85, NA),
  vard.glo3 = c(NA, NA, 100),
  vard = c("", "glo1: 15 | glo2: 85", "glo3: 100")
)
```

In this example, the "vara.(...)" columns were created using "vara". It is the same for "varb.(...)", "varc.(...)" et "vard.(...)"

I am trying to build a function that will allow me to complete my new columns vara.(...), varb.(...), varc.(...) and vard.(...). So that for example :
If vara is not empty, and vara.(...) is empty then it puts me "No" in vara.(...).
Or if varc is not empty, and varc.(...) is empty then it puts me a 0 in varc.(...).

So I have two situations, either text columns or numeric columns.

I thought it would be simpler to make two lists:

```
var_names_char = c("vara", "varb")
var_names_num <- c("varc", "vard")
```

Knowing that my final result should be this one, does anyone have an idea how to unblock me?

```
df_result <- data.frame(
  id = c("id1", "id2", "id3"),
  vara.test = c("no", "yes", ""), 
  vara.bb = c("yes", "no", ""), 
  vara.some = c("no", "yes", ""),
  vara = c("bb", "test | some", ""),
  varb.other = c("yes", "no", "yes"),
  varb.blop = c("no", "yes", "yes"), 
  varb.some = c("yes", "no", "no"), 
  varb.test = c("no", "no", "yes"),
  varb = c("other | some", "blop", "other | blop | test"),
  varc.num1 = c(100, 25, 50),
  varc.num2 = c(0, 75, 25),
  varc.num3 = c(0, 0, 25),
  varc = c("num1: 100", "num1: 25 | num2: 75", "num1: 50 | num2: 25 | num3: 25"),
  vard.glo1 = c(NA, 15, 0),
  vard.glo2 = c(NA, 85, 0),
  vard.glo3 = c(NA, 0, 100),
  vard = c("", "glo1: 15 | glo2: 85", "glo3: 100")
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your example. You have values like `c("", "", 100)` which mix character values and number values in the same vector but you can't do that in R. Either everyhing has to be a character `c("", "", "100")` or your have numeric values with NA: `c(NA, NA, 100)` or you have a list of mixed types. `list("", "", 100)`. What is actually in your data.frame?

Comment: Excuse me, you are right, I just corrected my example. Thank you very much!

Comment: You now have >= 15 reputation so now you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). It would be better if you cut and paste your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem. I had mixed up the loops quite a bit...:

```
fonc_comp <- function(df, var_names_char, var_names_num) {
      col_daught_char <- names(df)[grepl(paste0("^(", paste(var_names_char, collapse = "|"), ")[.].*"), names(df))]
      col_daught_num <- names(df)[grepl(paste0("^(", paste(var_names_num, collapse = "|"), ")[.].*"), names(df))]
      if (!is.null(var_names_char) && length(var_names_char) > 0) {
        for (col_mere_char in var_names_char) {
          if (sum(!is.na(df[[col_mother_char]])) > 0) {
            for (col_char in col_daught_char [grep(col_mother_char, col_daught_char )]) {
              df[[col_char]][is.na(df[[col_char]]) & !is.na(df[[col_mother_char]])] <- "No"
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (!is.null(var_names_num) && length(var_names_num) > 0) {
        for (col_mother_num in var_names_num) {
          if (sum(!is.na(df[[col_mother_num]])) > 0) {
            for (col_num in col_daught_num[grep(col_mother_num, col_daught_num)]) {
              df[[col_num]][is.na(df[[col_num]]) & !is.na(df[[col_mother_num]])] <- 0
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return(df)
    }
```

Thank's ;-)